# Missing URI Parameter Facebook connect

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[app-id]&amp;redirect_uri=[url]&amp;client_secret=[secret]&amp;code=[code]

warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session

=> #<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>

irb(main):005:0> resp.body
=> "{\"error\":{\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"message\":\"Missing redirect_uri parameter.\"}}"
```

Any idea what the matter is ? Since, I am including redirect_uri

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, very unusual thought. Would be great if someone could expand on this.

When I made the call with Net::HTTP (ruby client), it didn't work, although when I used just "curl" things worked perfectly fine !